# Process Builder - Error

Tags: process-builder

The process builder is updating the old opportunities to closed lost if they haven't been touched in 30 days. It's checking the conditions and then I have two scheduled actions.

In the 2nd action, sends an email to the owner. and Update the records:

```
Contact is null boolean true
```

Updates records:

```
Contact ID XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Loss Reason picklist "value"
Stage Picklist Closed Lost
Opportunity Type picklist "value"
```

It works just fine. It's only that if there is a contact already, I don't want it to be replaced with my "Review Contact ID"

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: is this a time-based action in Process Builder? Remember that process builder only starts evaluating upon a DML change to the target (Opportunity) object.

Comment: @cropredy - thanks for coming back to me. I have edited my question :). I have simplified the process, because not all opp owners were contacts, so I didn't work to relate the owner as a contact.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the screen shot for the Scheduled Action criteria. My suspicion is that you want to be comparing the value of Opportunity.Contact__c to null, not Opportunity.Contact